# Listening to 4th and 5th mouse buttons in Chrome apps (for browser navigation)

Tags: mouseevent, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome packaged app with an embedded webview. There are buttons for history back and forth like in a browser, but I would like to listen for keyboard and mouse events too.

This snippets catches both ALT-arrow keys and multimedia buttons, but not the 4th and 5th mouse buttons which are normally used for browser navigation:

```
$("html").on("keydown mousedown mouseup", function (event, data) {
    console.info(event);
});
```

How do I detect the mentioned mouse buttons?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/new-event-for-non-primary-button-click/1527 (of course, that discussion is in early stages)

Comment: @Xan: Does this mean that at present it is simply not possible to catch the 4th and 5th mouse button?

Comment: I don't know for sure, and therefore not making it an answer.